# No success using Header Redirect

Tags: php, mysql, redirect, header

I'm having a problem redirecting users to a signup page. Users are redirected if the auto-login script I wrote fails (because their username and password are not in the database). Strange thing, I could swear this all worked yesterday. lol

The script doesn't seem to reach the second redirect. The first redirect works fine if a username and password are found in the database, otherwise all one sees is a blank white page.

I've tried rewriting, tinkering and including `ob_start` at the top of the page, to no avail! Any help would be massively appreciated.

```
    $username=$row2['username'];
    $password=$row2['password'];

    $login = login ($username, $password);
    if ($login) {
        $_SESSION ['user_id'] = $login;
        header('Location: promotion_list.php?user='. $row1['username']);
        exit (); 
    }else {
        header('Location: quick_signup.php?fid='. $row1['id']);
        exit();
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure that your redirect page has some content?

Comment: Yes, there is a form.

Comment: What does your `login()` function return?

Comment: Do you have errors turned on?

Comment: Are you sure that the redirect is executed? Does it not fail with error? Check PHP error reporting. A common problem that prevents `header` redirect is if there was any output before (e.g. a single white space is enough to prevent the redirect.)

Comment: Try giving full page url in redirect. Also make sure your errors are turn on.

Comment: No errors are returned. Just a blank white page.

Comment: `ini_set('display_errors',1);  error_reporting(E_ALL);` -- include this line in your script top.

Comment: @Amal ...Tried your suggestion, still getting only a blank white screen.

Comment: All errors are turned on.

Comment: @BernieAllen, Amal's suggestion seems really probable, and on some systems it can be quite hard to get the errors, try setting the redirect to be just some chars without code

Comment: Yeah, I can't get it to output any error messages. I suspect the script just isn't reaching the redirect in question for some reason (not obvious to me).

Comment: Have you tried, echoing the $login variable to see if its returning the BOOL your expecting, based on your if else statement, im assuming its looking for a true/false flag

try echoing the 4login variable before your redirects to see if the failed ones show up as false or 0

hope this helps you discover the problem.

Comment: Hey, Dave. I gave that a try; $login won't echo.

Comment: Try just setting it to false -  if(FALSE)

Comment: What happens if you use the browser to go to the url?

Comment: Unfortunately it's important that users are redirected to the page in question, for optimal convenience. I could, in theory, provide a direct link to the page; but that would compromise usability.

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions. Really appreciated.

Comment: I mean, what happens if you redirect manually, just to see what output you will get there.

Comment: Everything works exactly as scripted if I redirect manually. It's the d*mn header-redirect. Really frustrating. :)

Comment: try echoing $row1['id'], and make sure is as expected

Comment: Nothing, just a blank screen. It will output an error only if there is something wrong (for example if I forget a semi-colon), otherwise I just get a blank white screen.

Comment: I think we are getting there.. try putting a static value instead of $row1['id']. Also, try scanning the rest of the code for ini_set('display_errors,0) & htacces to see if you can disable the hiding of error messages. if all this fails, try locating php error log

Comment: There are no errors at all. The problem is that it's like the second redirect just doesn't exist. I can completely remove it and I have exactly what I have now. ...I can't figure it out*

Comment: Again, have you tried echoing $row1['id']? Tried replacing it with a static value?

Comment: The site uses "dozens" of redirects throughout. This particular one is a bit of an anomaly. haha Time sink*

Comment: See my last comment, my guess is either using $row1['id'] is creating an error, or that the value inside this variable is breaking the redirect, echoing it will solve your problem

Comment: I tried that, Skarlinski. Nothing...Just a blank white screen. Nothing gets output unless there is an error.

Comment: I'll investigate that idea more closely!

Comment: of course you disabled the ob_start from before, right?

Comment: It's disabled it now. ;) ...I tried changing $row1['id'] to $row2['id'] and to $row1['username'] just to test around. Also tried changing the 'else' statement to an 'else if ()' statement. Nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value inside $row1['id'] is either not set, or the string within is breaking your header request.

Do this :

```
   $username=$row2['username'];
    $password=$row2['password'];

    $login = login ($username, $password);

    echo $row1['id']; die(); // This will output the value


    if ($login) {
        $_SESSION ['user_id'] = $login;
        header('Location: promotion_list.php?user='. $row1['username']);
        exit (); 
    }else {
        header('Location: quick_signup.php?fid='. $row1['id']);
        exit();
    }
```

Comment: $row1['id'] is the value I use to obtain the values of $row2[] (using a while loop). $row2[] does its job without problem, which would suggest $row1['id'] is in working order. ...The problem is that $row1['id'] doesn't execute when it is passed in the header-redirect. :(

Comment: indeed, it is like the entire "else" statement does not even exist

Comment: use if(false), to make sure you are running the else

Comment: Assuming the value is ok is problematic. I am 95% sure this is the problem. Using the value is creating an error, error reporting is off, and what you get is a blank page.

Comment: Thanks, I gave both of your suggestions a whirl. The value in $row1['id'] is "67" in this case. I tried replacing $row1['id'] with a $_GET variable. I also tried changing the if statement to (!$login) and every other variation of false I could think of, without success. I also tried change the else statement to an if (false) statement and also else if (false) statement...and a lot of other things. Really appreciating the suggestions here, man. :)

Comment: For error reporting this is what I use:  error_reporting (E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);

Comment: I think we have reached a point, that if we want to continue debugging you should show me more of the code (best if the whole page). Also, have you tried passing your code through netbeans / eclipse? It will clearly show if there is any syntax errors

Comment: Is there reason to belive that manually writing the url:  quick_signup.php?fid=67 
will return an empty page?
can you post the contents of quick_signup.php?

Comment: Writing quick_signup.php?fid=67 in the URL does not return an empty page - The page works like a charm, perfect, without problem. In fact, the whole system works exactly as intended except for the one header-redirect.  - I'm downloading Netbeans now! I will have to install it, later.  I'm using Notepad ++.

Comment: I tried the echo die() thing hours ago, my friend. Nothing is/was output...just a blank white screen. I think I may have to make a compromise and provide a direct link to the quick sign up page instead of using the header-redirect. I don't know what's going on, but it's strange. Thanks so much for all the assistance!!

Comment: Note: I solved this problem several days ago by rewriting the script. No compromises were made. There was an issue with one of the while loops that I still can't explain. Giving you the green-check, Sharlinski. Thanks for your input.